# Sum of Complex Numbers and Modulus Inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, summation

Let $z_{1}, \dots, z_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$. Then, there exists a subset $S \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that:

$
\left| \displaystyle\sum_{j \in S}z_{j} \right| \geq \displaystyle\frac{1}{6}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|z_{j}|
$

---

I'm not sure on how to start for the proof of this result (I need it as a lemma for some proof involving complex measures). Clearly, the case where all $z_{j}=0$ is trivial.

What would be a way to prove this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Startning hint: of the four quadrants defined by the real and imaginary axes, one of them must contain at least $n/4$ of the numbers $z_j$.